# How to properly create recursive comments in templates django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to create a tree like comment section in my site, but I can't handle to work it as expected. I just ended up with a mess there, but it seems to me that model works perfectly.. Maybe I am wrong, but I assume there is a template logic problems. I've attached a screenshot of how it looks now. As you can see, comments are duplicating each other and do not construct a tree like stuff. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Views.py

It is the main View that rendering social network profile page.

```
class ProfileDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'user_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = User.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('slug'))
        settings = Settings.objects.get(user=user_profile.id)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user_profile.id).order_by('-post_date')
        subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(author=user_profile.id).order_by('price')
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      context={
                          'profile': user_profile,
                          'posts': posts,
                          'settings': settings,
                          'subscriptions': subscriptions,
                          'form': comment_form
                      })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = User.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('slug'))

        if 'subscruption_action' in request.POST:
            action = request.POST['subscruption_action']
            if action == 'unfollow':
                request.user.follows.remove(user_profile.id)
            else:
                request.user.follows.add(user_profile.id)
            request.user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': user_profile.slug}))


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author=self.object.id)
        context['settings'] = Settings.objects.get(user=self.object.id)
        return context
```

View func that register new comment:

```
def add_comment(request, slug, pk):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        try:
            answered_comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=cleaned_data.get('parent_comment'))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            new_comment = Comment(
                user=request.user,
                post=post,
                body=cleaned_data.get('body'),
            )
            new_comment.save()
        else:
            new_comment = Comment(
                user=request.user,
                post=post,
                body=cleaned_data.get('body'),
                comment_to_reply=answered_comment
            )
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid!')
    return redirect('index')
```

Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    comment_to_reply = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

comments_template.html

```
{% if post.comments %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <a name="comment-{{ comment.id }}"></a>
        <div class="row" id="{{ comment.id }}">
            <div class="shadow-sm mb-3 card border-0 p-3 bg-light">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <strong>{{ comment.user.username }}</strong>
                    <a href="#comment-{{ comment.id }}"></a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_at }}</small>
                </div>
                {% if form %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">{{ comment.body }}</div>
                    <div class="col text-end">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="return show_comments_form({{ comment.id }})">Reply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div>{{ comment.body }}</div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if comment.replies %}
            <div class="offset-md-3">
            {% for comment in comment.replies.all %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col offset-md-1">
                    <div class="shadow-sm mb-3 border-0 p-3 bg-light" id="{{ comment.id }}">
                        {% if form %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <strong><a href="{% url 'profile_detail' comment.user.slug %}">{{ comment.user.username }}</a></strong>
                                <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_at }}</small>
                                <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <small class="text-muted">Reply to - {{ comment.comment_to_reply.user }}</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 text-end">
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="return show_comments_form({{ comment.id }})">Reply</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            <strong><a href="{% url 'profile_detail' reply.user.slug %}">{{ comment.user.username }}</a></strong>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ reply.created_at }}</small>
                            <p>{{ reply.body }}</p>
                            <small class="text-muted">Reply to - {{ comment.comment_to_reply.user }}</small>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: Try using the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag.

Comment: The inner for loop variable name is the same as the outer for loop variable name. You are using comment for both loops, which can cause conflicts. Consider using a different variable name for the inner loop.

Comment: See I dump the right code which I think should work for you [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/js/ZANyhNNNh_HnfjSY)

Comment: @Fractalism, thanks for a reply! I've tried it already. It looks exactly as the first cycle in the template example, but leads to the same results

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, one sec, I'll try it

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, does not worked out :(
Still the same result

Comment: Same as you showed in screenshot? Can you also share view associated with it?

Comment: Sure, one sec. I'll update the question

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, update it!

Comment: @jmur With regards to my first comment, I meant that you can modify this template  such that it can recursively `include` itself to render all subcomments.

Comment: @Fractalism, okay, it sounds well, but how it is suppose to look like? I've included another for cycle in different template and import it backwards to the main one. It looks now smth like that: 
{% if comment.replies %}
    {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        {% include 'recursive_comments.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

I understand include tag concept, but I've never realized recursive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could structure a recursive template in the following manner:
(This is just a bare metal example to illustrate the concept)

**comments_template.html** - render all comments under a post

```
{% if post.comments %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        {% include 'recursive_comment.html' with comment=comment %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**recursive_comment.html** - render a comment and include its replies (if any)

```
{% comment %} insert comment markup here {% endcomment %}

{% if comment.replies %}
    {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        {% include 'recursive_comment.html' with comment=reply %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. It helped, really. I didn't expect that template can be included in.. itself, so just create cycle-in-cycle structure with include, ahahahah. I'll remember it for the future, thanks again. With treelike structure - done. 
Actually, comments duplicating each other in branches and in main section. Maybe, you know how to fix this too?

Comment: Actually, fixed duplicating thing by myself. Don't be bothered. Good luck!